# Изменить каталог nginx по умолчанию

Tags: nginx

По умолчанию, при открытии ip в бразере. Попадаю на страницу
`Welcome to nginx!`
Файл расположен в каталоге /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
Хочу изменить данный каталог, иду в /etc/nginx/conf.d/ каталог пустой.

Где тот самый конфиг, в котором возможно изменить путь? В /etc/nginx/sites-available/default в файле не указан подобный путь

Comment: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf в данном файле тоже не указан путь /usr/share/nginx/html/. Где тот самый конфиг, который указывает путь?

Comment: А такие директории /etc/nginx/sites-available и /etc/nginx/sites-enabled имеются? Согласно новых традиции, в первую можно и нужно складывать конфиги (во множественном числе), а во вторую (для включения) бросают симлинки на эти конфиги.